# How do I specify an asp.net mvc 5 resource file in a VB Class Data Annotation?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, data-annotations

VS 2013, MVC 5, VB, Entity Framework

This is part of my Class:

```
Public Class Order
....
Private mFirstName As String
<Required(ErrorMessage:="First name required - hard coded")>
Public Property FirstName() As String
  Get
    Return mFirstName
  End Get
  Set(ByVal value As String)
    mFirstName = value
  End Set
End Property
....
```

I want to setup a resource file to allow error messages to change with different countries.  What would I write to have the error message pulled from a resource file named ErrorMessages.resx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examples for doing this are mostly in C#, and finding the VB equivalent was difficult, at least for me, and I thought other VB programmers might appreciate the proper syntax.

The C# answer is:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType=typeof(ErrorMessages),ErrorMessageResourceName="FirstNameRequired")]
```

What was difficult was to find the proper VB operator to apply for the C# "typeof" operator.  In VB the line above is:

```
<Required(ErrorMessageResourceName:="FirstNameRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType:=GetType(Resources.ErrorMessages))>
```

in the lines above, the Name/Value pairs are stored in ErrorMessages.resx (see how to create below), and "FirstNameRequired" is the Name of the string that will hold the actual text to be displayed.

Just to cover the bases:

1. What's pretty neat is that VS2013 automatically creates the Class and type definitions for the resource file and they show up in Intellisense, as in the VB line above 'Resources.ErrorMessages'.
2. It's also important to note the Data Annotation operators can have only one or the other of the two error message string properties, so the property "ErrorMessage" had to be removed as seen in the code lines in this answer post.
3. To use a [Global Resource file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247246(v=vs.100).aspx) (local files are possible), on the project node do an Add > Add ASP.NET Folder > Add App_GlobalResources.  Then inside that folder Add > New Item > Resources File.  After that the Name-Value pairs can be added, and then later additional country-culture resource files can be added, and online documentation for this process is fairly plentiful.  [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-validation), and [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bz9tc508(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) for the country-culture.

The MSDN page that lists all of the data annotations is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations(v=vs.110).aspx);  But I didn't find enough code samples to readily explain how to take advantage of the properties listed.

Hope this is helpful for someone else.

Best Regards,
Alan